# how to package my python pytorch program for android?

Tags: python, android, pytorch

my codes is python pytorch.
I build it to .exe, it can work at windows.
How to package the codes for android.
I hope it can work at android.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know how to call an exe program in android, but I can give you some other advice. According to your needs, maybe you can learn about **Chaquopy**.

Chaquopy provides everything you need to include Python components in an Android app, including:

(1)Full integration with Android Studio’s standard Gradle build system.

(2)Simple APIs for calling Python code from Java/Kotlin, and vice versa.

(3)A wide range of third-party Python packages, including SciPy, OpenCV, TensorFlow and many more.

With Chaquopy, you can run python programs directly on Android. I have experience running sklearn programs on Android before. If you have any questions, you can continue to ask.

Chaquopy official website:https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/